# Valid variable name in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I'm using perl and Template::Toolkit to generate some texts. In the perl program, I defined a hash ref such as

```
my $user = { "user-name" => "John" };
```

and passed it to `Template::Toolkit` in order to generate `John` with the template file. In the template file I wrote

```
[% user-name %]
```

But unfortunately, `user-name` seemed to be recognized as a subtraction expression (`user` minus `name`) by `Template::Toolkit`.

To confirm my suspicions, I looked into [the manual](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html) of `Template::Toolkit` to find the valid tokens to use in the variable name but found nothing.

So my questions are:

1. Could you give the list of valid tokens for variable names of
   `Template::Toolkit`?
2. Could I use some "escaping method" in the template file so that the
   variable name in perl program could remain `user-name`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, a valid perl variable is a valid template toolkit variable.

- The variable should always start with a non numeric, non symbolic character `[ A to Z and _ ]`
- Variable can only contain `a to z`, `0 to 9` and `_` (underscore) characters.
- Variable names cannot contain special symbols (it includes `'-'` symbol ).

Eg:

`$user-name` is not a valid perl variable. but 
`$user_name` is valid.

Here is what perl interpreter throws for your code

```
$ my $user = { user-name => "John" };                                                                                                      
Compile error: Bareword "user" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 294) line 5.
```

If you really want to use `'user-name'` then you should define like this

```
$ my $user = { "user-name" => "John" };      
$ my $data = { user => $user };
```

And you should access it in your tt2 file like this:

```
[% user.item('user-name') %]
```

Comment: Thanks. The `{ user-name => "John" }` part is a typo and I fixed it in the question. And `[%user.item('user-name') %]` worked like a charm. Really appreciate that!

Comment: Unfortunately, a TT variable starting with an underscore is not expanded by TT. [% _lang %] remains empty, although the variable hash does contain { _lang => 'some value' }